# How can I sum the time based on usernames?

Tags: bash, scripting, time, for

Basically, I want to see how much time every user spent logged in.

`(username) pts/0       (IP adress)     Tue Dec 12 17:51 - 18:14  (00:22) -` this is how one line looks in the last command. The username is between characters 1-9, the time is between 67-71. There are multiple logins from each user, so I want to sum the time based on their username. I already counted how many times one user logged in using

```
echo `last | sort | cut -c1-9 | uniq -c | sort -n | head -$y`
```

in a bash script. Is it possible to add up the time of each user using a format similar to this? I was thinking of a for loop, but have no ide how to set it up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ac` command for this.  Part of the `psacct` package.

```
$ last|head
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Tue Nov 20 18:40   still logged in
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Mon Nov 19 22:19 - 23:09  (00:50)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Wed Nov 14 19:36 - 19:45  (00:09)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Fri Nov  9 11:43 - 11:56  (00:12)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Thu Nov  8 21:58 - 22:00  (00:02)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Mon Nov  5 17:37 - 18:30  (00:53)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Fri Nov  2 19:45 - 20:39  (00:54)
steve    pts/1        cpc79909-stkp12- Fri Nov  2 17:34 - 18:31  (00:57)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Fri Nov  2 16:01 - 18:30  (02:29)
steve    pts/0        cpc79909-stkp12- Thu Nov  1 21:10 - 23:14  (02:04)
$ ac -p
        steve                               33.79
        total       33.79
$
```

Or use `awk` ?

```
$ last | awk '$NF ~ /^\([0-9]+:[0-9]+\)$/{split($NF,t,":");a[$1]+=t[1]*60+t[2]}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}'
```